# How to sort a list of class objects on one of its fields using Lambda Expressions?

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

I was writing a code to validate states of my object. The code I wrote sorts the input list of objects and then does a range check.

```
private boolean validateStates(List<ConcessionState> concessionStateList) {
    long startRange,endRange = 0;
    Collections.sort(concessionStateList , new Comparator<ConcessionState>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ConcessionState o1, ConcessionState o2) {
            return (int)(long)(o1.getRangeStart() - o2.getRangeStart());
        }
........
}
```

Is there a way to write this sort using Lambda expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-).

As follows:

```
private boolean validateStates(List<ConcessionState> concessionStateList) {
    long startRange,endRange = 0;
    Collections.sort(concessionStateList,
                     Comparator.comparing(ConcessionState::getRangeStart));
    .......
}
```

If you want it in descending order, you do

```
    Comparator.comparing(ConcessionState::getRangeStart)
              .reversed()
```